# Google Earth: Shortest distance between point (Place) and nearest point on a polygon (Country)

Tags: google-maps, distance, google-earth

Using Google Earth, I am trying to find the simplest way to calculate the shortest distances of the geodesic lines between a specific set of points (lat/long locations) and the nearest points on a specific set of polygons (countries). I have tried to use measurement but the set of points is far too large to calculate the values for every point to every country in the world. Plus, it is very subjective. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Alternatives using Javascript, etc is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula).

Comment: Sounds like you need a rather sophisticated analysis tool. You might look into QGIS which may have the functionality you're looking for.